# Python requests.get content encoding problem

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, python-requests

I am working on a scraping project using requests.get. The html file contains a relative path of the form href="../_static/new_page.html" for the css file.
I am using the below code to get the html file

```
import requests
url = "www.example.com"
req = requests.get(url)
req.content
```

All the href containing "../_static" become "_static/...". I tried req.text and changed the encoding to utf-8, which is the encoding of the page. However, I am always getting the same result. I also tried urllib.request.get, and I also got the same problem.
Any suggestions!

Comment: Just use replace() ?

Comment: Thank you QHarr,  but the idea is to develop an algorithm that reads many pages, without knowing where I will find this "../" referring to parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Adam.

Yes, it will be related to encoding format when you write the response content to Html file.

but you just have to consider the encoding type of response content itself.

Just check the encoding type of your requests library.

```py
response = requests.get("url")
print(response.encoding)
```

You just need to choose the right encoding type like above.

`response.encoding = "utf-8"`

or

`response.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"`

or

`response.encoding = "utf-8-sig"`

...

Hope my answer helps you.

Regards